# Difference between two dates in java using joda API

Tags: java, jodatime

I have two dates date1 and date2, i need to get number of months between those two dates,
can any one help me to do.

Comment: `Duration duration = new Duration(dt1 , dt2);`

Answer (score 2):

```
int result = Months.monthsBetween(date1, date2).getValue();
```